# Error when sending : mail Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException at testmail.main(testmail.java:4)

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, java

Trying to send mail using smtp, used all the necessary jar files(mail.jar and activation.jar) but always shows this error

[error shown on running testmail file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMnCD.png)

I have used two classes, one is to send the email and another one calls the function in that file

Code for sendmail.java

```
import javax.mail.*;    
import javax.mail.internet.*;    
class SendMail{  
    public static void send(String from,String password,String to,String sub,String msg){  
          //Get properties object    
          Properties props = new Properties();    
          props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");    
          props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");    
          props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",    
                    "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");    
          props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");    
          props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");    
          //get Session   
          Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,    
           new javax.mail.Authenticator() {    
           protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {    
           return new PasswordAuthentication(from,password);  
           }    
          });    
          //compose message    
          try {    
           MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);    
           message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));    
           message.setSubject(sub);    
           message.setText(msg);    
           //send message  
           Transport.send(message);    
           System.out.println("message sent successfully");    
          } catch (MessagingException e) {throw new RuntimeException(e);}    
             
    }  
}
```

Code for testmail.java

```
public class testmail{    
 public static void main(String[] args) {    
     //from,password,to,subject,message  
     SendMail.send("myemail","mypassword","reciever","hello javatpoint","How r u?");
     System.out.println("message sent successfully");    
     //change from, password and to  
 }    
}
```

both the files are compiling but when I execute the testmail file the error is shown

I have used the apache tomcat 9.0 server

Answer (score 0):

plz check your version of `javax.mail`, i am using `1.6.2`, there is no problem to run your code.